# How is possible to combine 'excludes' with 'default' in schema?

Tags: python, validation, cerberus

`field_1` must be 0 by default, but not allowed with `field_2`. My try:

```
from cerberus import Validator

schema = {
    'value_1': {
        'type': 'integer',
        'default': 0
    },
    'value_2': {
        'type': 'integer',
        'excludes': ['value_1', ]
    }
}
v = Validator(schema)

for doc in [{}, {'value_2': 1}, {'value_2': 1, 'value_2': 1}]:
    if not v.validate(doc, schema):
        print(v.errors)
    else:
        print(v.normalized(doc))
```

I got:

```
{'value_1': 0}
{'value_2': ["'value_1' must not be present with 'value_2'"]}
{'value_2': ["'value_1' must not be present with 'value_2'"]}
```

I want to validate second document without errors with normalized result `{'value_1': 0, 'value_2': 1}`. How can I achieve the desired result?

**EDIT** More clear explanation of my goals:
- I want to raise error if `value_1` and `value_2` exists in incoming document, but set `0` to `value_1` if this key not exists in document.
- I want to do it inside cerberus validation/normalization procedure and want to solve it by changing validation schema or validator

Comment: You cannot use default and at the same time exclude it from other field. You can set default values for missing fields in the document which adds the defaults if its not present.

Comment: @Reck I think this can be done with the help of [`oneof`](http://docs.python-cerberus.org/en/stable/validation-rules.html#of-rules)  but I can not understand how

Comment: @El Ruse one can obviously not define normalization within the oneof-rule.

Comment: @funky-future yep, this is just the case when the overall design of my schema is wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Quick Answer (TL;DR)

- validation and normalization can always be separated into distinct steps

### Detailed Answer

#### Context

- python 2.7
- cerberus data-structure validation and normalization tool

#### Problem

- **Scenario:** Developer ElRusoDevoWoze wishes to combine validation with data normalization, in order to provide default values for missing fields.

#### Solution

- separate data validation from data normalization

#### Rationale

- rationale ;; validation and normalization can be thought of as *separate processes*

  - proc1 ;; distinguish unacceptable inputs from acceptable inputs

    - (garbage vs treasure)
    - (authenticated vs unauthenticated)
    - (well-formed vs non-well-formed)
  - proc2 ;; optimize the content of acceptable inputs

#### Example

- The following example creates and applies two schemas
- One schema provides the default values, the other does the validation

  ```
  import pprint
  import yaml
  from cerberus import Validator
  pass

  schema_vali = yaml.safe_load('''
    value_1:
      type:       integer
      excludes:   value_2
      required:   True
    value_2:
      type:       integer
      excludes:   value_1
      required:   True
  ''')
  pass

  schema_norm = yaml.safe_load('''
    value_1:
      default:    0
  ''')
  pass

  sample_docs = yaml.safe_load('''
    ¯ {}                            ## doc0
    ¯ {'value_1': 1}                ## doc1
    ¯ {'value_2': 1}                ## doc2
    ¯ {'value_1': 1, 'value_2': 1}  ## doc3
    ''')
  pass

  vccvali = Validator(schema_vali)
  vccnorm = Validator(schema_norm)
  pass

  for ijj,doc in enumerate(sample_docs):
    if vccnorm.validate(doc):
      print("{ijj} NORM-YESS! -->".format(ijj=ijj)),
      print(vccnorm.normalized(doc))
      doc = vccnorm.normalized(doc)
    if not vccvali.validate(doc):
      print("{ijj} VALI-NOPE! -->".format(ijj=ijj)),
      print(vccvali.errors)
    else:
      print("{ijj} VALI-YESS! -->".format(ijj=ijj)),
      print(vccvali.normalized(doc))
      doc = vccnorm.normalized(doc)
  pass
  ```

#### Output result

```
  0 NORM-YESS! --> {'value_1': 0}
  0 VALI-YESS! --> {'value_1': 0}
  1 NORM-YESS! --> {'value_1': 1}
  1 VALI-YESS! --> {'value_1': 1}
  2 VALI-YESS! --> {'value_2': 1}
  3 VALI-NOPE! --> {'value_1': ["'value_2' must not be present with 'value_1'"], 'value_2': ["'value_1' must not be present with 'value_2'"]}
```

Comment: Tnx. As I say in comments to question: " this is just the case when the overall design of my schema is wrong" I didn't delete this question only for educational purposes. And now we have answer which can be marked as accepted :)

Answer (score 0):

This is just upon understanding your requirement. And this works.

```
from cerberus import Validator

schema = {
    'value_1': {
        'type': 'integer',
        'default': 0,
    },
    'value_2': {
        'type': 'integer',
        'excludes': ['value_1']
    }
}

v = Validator(schema)

for doc in [{}, {'value_2': 1}, {'value_2': 2, 'value_1': 3}]:
    print('Doc: {}'.format(doc))
    n_doc = {}
    if not v.validate(doc, schema):
        print('Error: {}'.format(v.errors))
        n_doc = v.normalized(doc)
        n_doc.update(v.normalized({}))
    else:
        n_doc = v.normalized(doc)
    print('Result: {}'.format(n_doc))
```

Result:

```
Doc: {}
Result: {'value_1': 0}
Doc: {'value_2': 1}
Error: {'value_2': ["'value_1' must not be present with 'value_2'"]}
Result: {'value_1': 0, 'value_2': 1}
Doc: {'value_1': 3, 'value_2': 2}
Error: {'value_2': ["'value_1' must not be present with 'value_2'"]}
Result: {'value_1': 0, 'value_2': 2}
```

Comment: I want to raise error if `value_1` and `value_2` exists in incoming document, **but** set default `0` to `value_1` if this key not exists in document. In your example document #3 will pass validation, it's not fits to my reqs

Comment: So this is an important information which you need to add in your question in a more descriptive way.

Comment: first sentence of my question body describe it. :) Your second example works, but completely ruin main goal of use data validation library, you move part of logic outside of validation procedure, it`s definitely not what i want .Tnx for your answer.