# Conditional requirement dependent on value of other fields

Tags: python, validation, conditional-statements, cerberus

Conditional requirement dependent on value of other fields in `Cerberus` has been discussed many times. Usage of `dependencies` doesn't meet the needs because fields can be `unknown` when conditions are satisfied. Usage of `oneof` was recommended but it may be too hard to work when several conditions and dependencies are met. What's the universal solution now?

Comment: You can use `oneof` with `excludes` to catch cases where an unknown field exists, by enumerating the known values and treating the unknown values as an exception. Do you have a specific example that you have tried that has caused you difficulty?

Answer (score 0):

### Quick Answer (TL;DR)

- The "composite validation" approach allows for conditional (context-aware) validation rules.
- The python `cerberus` package supports composite validation "out of the box".
- Composite validation allows for easily-human-readable rules with highly-flexible granularity on triggering conditions.

### Detailed Answer

#### Context

- python 2.7
- cerberus validation package

#### Problem

- Developer JasperHuangCreator wishes to apply triggering conditions to finely-tuned validation rules.

#### Solution

- This approach can be accomplished with composite data validation.
- Under this use-case, composite validation simply means creating a sequential list of validation rules, such that:

  - Each individual rule operates on a composite data variable
  - Each individual rule specifies a "triggering condition" for when the rule applies
  - Each individual rule produces one of three mutually-exclusive validation outcomes: `validation-success`, `validation-fail`, or `validation-skipped`

#### Example

Sample documents

```
aadocuments = []
aadocuments.append(yaml.safe_load('''
    person_fname:         homer
    person_lname:         himpson
    person_age:           33
    prize_caption:        free beer for life
    prize_email:          prizes@abcbooze.com
    prize_category:       alchohol
'''))
aadocuments.append(yaml.safe_load('''
    person_fname:         helen
    person_lname:         himpson
    person_age:           16
    prize_caption:        free ammo for life
    prize_email:          prizes@zzzguns.com
    prize_category:       firearms
  '''))
```

Sample validation rules

```
- rule_caption:     check-required-fields
  rule_vpath:       "@"
  validation_schema:
    person_fname:
      type: string
      required: true
    person_lname:
      type: string
      required: true
    person_age:
      type: string
      required: true

- rule_caption:     check-age-range
  rule_vpath:       '@|@.person_age'
  validation_schema:
    person_age:
      "min": 2
      "max": 120

- rule_caption:     check-underage-minor
  rule_vpath:       '[@]|[? @.person_age < `18`]'
  validation_schema:
    prize_category:
      type: string
      allowed: ['pets','toys','candy']
    prize_email:
      type:     string
      regex:    '[\w]+@.*'
```

- The code above is a YAML formatted representation of multiple validation rules.
- The code above specifies the triggering condition through use of the `rule_vpath` name-value pair.

#### Rationale

- This approach can be extended to any arbitrary level of complexity.
- This approach is easily comprehensible by humans (although the jmespath syntax can be a challenge at first).
- Any arbitrarily complex set of conditions and constraints can be established using this approach.

#### Pitfalls

- The above example uses jmespath syntax to specify `rule_vpath`, which tells the system when to trigger specific rules, this adds a dependency on jmespath.

#### See also

- [complete code example on github](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/dreftymac/trypublic/master/lab2019/composite-validation/demo_composite_validation_001a.py)